# Using xSense in mrpt

Tags: c++, slam

I am a new user of mrpt library ! My project is about using IMU data (xSense 4th generation).

However, I guess that some xSense data are already treated through an AHRS filter (sort of embedded Kalman filter from the documentation). And I am not able to find in mrpt library which data are exactly retrieved from the sensor ? Could you help me out finding where this information is given ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can grab raw data as well. See all the available fields in the observation data type [`CObservationIMU`](http://reference.mrpt.org/devel/classmrpt_1_1obs_1_1_c_observation_i_m_u.html) (though, not all fields are available for all IMUs...).

You can start by running the [`rawlog-grabber`](http://www.mrpt.org/list-of-mrpt-apps/application-rawlog-grabber/) with an example configuration file for XSens IMUs (see the list of config files at the bottom of the former link) and inspect the resulting `.rawlog` dataset with [RawLogViewer](http://www.mrpt.org/list-of-mrpt-apps/rawlogviewer/).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jose ! After some research in the mrpt library I could find in Xsdata Identifier file what was exactly the data retrieved from the xSense [https://github.com/MRPT/mrpt/blob/master/libs/hwdrivers/src/xSens_MT4/xstypes/include/xsens/xsdataidentifier.h]